# How to exclude subfolders and files in the Search pane of LightTable?

Tags: lighttable

What is the syntax of the `Locations` field in the *Find and Replace* pane of LightTable? (which appears when hitting `CTRL-SHIFT-F`, or `CTRL+SPACE` then `Searcher: show`)

I would like to exclude all files of the `docs/` subfolder, as well as all `*.txt` and `*.csv` files of my workspace. What should I enter in the `Locations` field to exclude them from a search & replace?

Or inversely, I'd like to include only the files from the `src/` subfolder. How would I accomplish that?

Comment: Per default, the Locations field contains `<workspace>`, which looks like a symbolic location. [Sublime Text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13706965/limit-file-search-scope-in-sublime-text-2) also uses symbolic locations and allows to include/exclude folders and files from the search with patterns and symbolic locations, such as `-/docs/*,-*.csv,-*.txt` or `<open folders>, <open files>`. Do we have such features in LightTable also?

Comment: Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable/blob/a950c188f2cee0fa397ea7ad0bfbc4ccdad473d0/src/lt/objs/search.cljs#L46) of LightTable (as of version 0.7.2), `<workspace>` is the only symbolic location being supported, and it must be entered as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to exclude directories or file patterns right now. However, you can specify which directories to include. You will have to write the whole path though ([relative paths use Light Table's application directory](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/light-table-discussion/gUwEP0y-hhw/NmijwpWL8YMJ)). If you want to have more than one path you can separate them by using a comma:

```
/absolute/path/to/first/dir, /absolute/path/to/second/dir
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Specifying absolute paths does work. And as discussed in the Google Group thread you mentioned, I also found that `~` does not expand to the user home on my Mac.